# multiple ng-pattern on one input

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation, ng-pattern

I want to use a single input box to search either by index (0, 1, etc etc) or by full hash. The below regex works fine, but if I have a valid hash and search by index or vice versa, the results are not what I am wanting. IS there a better way to approach this without having two inputs? Ideally I'd like button 2 to be disabled if one pattern is matched, and button 1 disabled if the other is matched and split my regex into two different patterns. Is this possible? Is my approach even sensible?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" 
           class="form-control" 
           placeholder="Search by..." 
           name="query" ng-model="query" 
           ng-pattern="/^[0-9a-fA-F]{64}$|^\d+$/" 
           required>
</div>
<button type="submit" 
        class="btn btn-default" 
        ng-click="searchBar.$valid &&  searchByHash()">
Hash</button>
<button type="submit" 
        class="btn btn-default" 
        ng-click="searchBar.$valid && searchByHeight()">
Height</button>
```

Comment: You'd need a custom directive for this that runs the two different regex parts (index _or_ patter) and tells you which one matched.